# How to detect after print from function that is using iframe for the print area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that starts printing a dialog with content from an `<iframe>`.

The question is how can I detect that the user Click "Print" or "Close" so I can reload the main page after that.

Here's my code:

```
function printPdf(url) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    // iframe.id = 'pdfIframe'
    iframe.className='pdfIframe'
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.onload = function () {

        setTimeout(function () {
            iframe.focus();



            iframe.contentWindow.print();

            URL.revokeObjectURL(url)

            // document.body.removeChild(iframe)
        }, 1);
    };
    iframe.src = url;
    // URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
}

<iframe id="PDF" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Comment: can you show your HTML code?

Comment: There is nothing special in my HTML code only an iframe which is populated by another function in java script from a database;